# QLikView escape character for special characters in Calculated Dimension

Tags: escaping, special-characters, qlikview

In a calculated dimension in Pivot Table, I would like to have special characters, in particular a single quote character inside a string in quotes. More precisely:

I would like to have in a calculated dimension a pick(match('Val1', 'Val2'),'Rep1','Rep2') where 'Rep1' is a string including a single quote, for instance 'Game O'Game'.

Is there an escape character for doing this, as the '\' character in Python ?

Please note I am working with calculated dimensions and not with the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an extra single qoute to escape:

'Game O''Game'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `chr()` function to achieve this. Passing the appropriate [decimal code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) to the function will return that character. Concatenate this with the rest of your string and you have your result:

```
pick(match('Val1', 'Val2'), 'Game O' & chr(39) & 'Game', 'Rep2')
```